# Adding a dynamic href attribute to dynamic link element in jQuery

Tags: jquery, wikipedia-api

I have a project where I'm using Wikipedia's API to retrieve some contents. I'm trying to update a "click here to read more link" dynamically, but I don't seem to be getting it and I've checked my code. Here is my search function:

```
searchEntry: function (entry)
    {
        var linker = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"+entry;
        var link = $('<div id="more" contenteditable="true"><p><a href="#" id="morelink">Click here</a> to read more.</p></div>');
        $("div#more a").attr("href", linker);
        console.log(link);
        $.getJSON(wikiSearch.wbase+"action=parse&format=json&prop=text&section=0&page=" + entry + "&redirects&callback=?", function(data)
        {   

            if (!data.error)
            {
                var markup = data.parse.text["*"];
                if (typeof markup !== "undefined")
                {
                    $("#entry").text(entry).show();
                    var blurb = $('<div id="articleText"></div>').html(markup);

                    // remove links as they will not work
                    blurb.find('a').each(function() { $(this).replaceWith($(this).html()); });

                    // remove any references
                    blurb.find('sup').remove();

                    // remove cite error
                    blurb.find('.mw-ext-cite-error').remove();
                    $('#article').html($(blurb).find('p'));

                    $("#article").append(link);
                    // console.log(markup);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $("#warning").text(data.error.info).show();
            }
            $(".spinner").hide();
        });
        $("#article").show();
        // if($("#article").show())
        // {
        //  wikiSearch.showMore();
        // }
    },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link is contained in the variable `link` but hasn't been attached to the DOM yet, so when you try to search for it, using `$("div#more a")` nothing is found because jQuery is searching the HTML of your page, not the HTML you dynamically added to some variable.

You have two options:

**1)** Put the link in the HTML of your page instead of trying to dynamically create it, thus you could just do this:

```
var link = $('#more a');
link.attr('href', linker);
```

**2)** If it has to be dynamically created, add the `href` attribute when you create it, and then make sure you attach it to the DOM. Something like:

```
var linker = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + entry;
var link = $('<div id="more" contenteditable="true"><p><a href="' + linker + '" id="morelink">Click here</a> to read more.</p></div>');

// The link is now only stored in the variable we created. 
// We need to add it to our page. You can replace 'body' with the parent element that the link should be added to.
$('body').append(link);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, use .prop instead of .attr (method signature is the same)

Second, the a tag doesn't exist on the page when you're trying to manipulate its href, rather = it only exists as a string variable.  Try setting the href attribute of the link when you create it as a variable like so:

```
     var hrefLink = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"+entry;
     var link = $('<div id="more" contenteditable="true"><p><a href=' + hrefLink  + ' id="morelink">Click here</a> to read more.</p></div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because the jQuery $("") is supposed to be an element selector and shouldn't have any HTML structure in it.  $("div#more a") can't find anything because (as far as I can tell) that code isn't actually in the DOM which is where jQuery is searching. Couldn't you do something like this:

```
var link = '<div id="more" contenteditable="true"><p><a href="'+ linker + '" id="morelink">Click here</a> to read more.</p></div>';
```

Then append that to your HTML.